# Expected ')' error when document.write with runat=server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page that requires a JavaScript function:

```
document.write('<head id='Head1' runat='server'/>');
```

But, when viewing the page in IE, I keep getting the "done but with errors..." message and when looking, I can see exactly what the problem is. When I 'View Source' I see this:

```
document.write("<head id="Head1"><link href="/myPage/WebResource.axd?..." type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><title>
    test
</title></head>");
```

It looks like something is putting a carriage return after `"<title>"` and after the title of the page. Therefore, the ')' is not on the same line as open-parenthesis giving me the error. Any idea how to get this to stop happening? I, personally, couldn't care less that the message is showing in IE, but not my call.

Comment: are you sure it is the fact that the line break is there? java usually does not care about line breaks, it cares about semicolons.

Comment: @Pow-Ian This question is about JS, which doesn't care much about neither.

Comment: Is that what you have? you are not opening and closing your quotes right if it is.

Comment: Are there really supposed to be spaces in d ocument.w rite("");? or did you mean `document.write("");`?

Comment: @NullUserException fair enough, but a missing semicolon can ruin your day sometimes in just this way.

Comment: What on earth is that code meaning to do ... ?  It looks like you're writing a server control using Javascript, which makes no sense.

Comment: Using runat server with a clientside document.write is not going to help you at all. The serverside will not be aware of the elements.

Comment: user, stop undoing useful edits. And the correct idiom is "I **couldn't** care less". "I could care less" [makes no sense](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om7O0MFkmpw).

Answer (score 4):

You have to either escape the quote marks you are using or use different quotes.

Also you are mixing server-side code with client-side. That won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your string is surrounded with quotes, but also contains quotes.

```
document.write('<head id="Head1">' +
    '<link href="/myPage/WebResource.axd?..." type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />' +
    '<title>test</title>' +
    '</head>');
```